# Как выбрать атрибут selected с помощью функции str_replace на PHP

Tags: php, html

Есть такой код:

```
<?php 

echo '<select size="1" name="country">'.str_replace('>'.$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'], 'selected>'.$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'], '<option value="0">Не скажу</option><option value="1">Украина</option><option value="2">Россия</option><option value="3">США</option><option value="4">Канада</option>').'</select>';

?>
```

После выбора информация сохраняется в БД и все вроде ок, но поле селектора не показывает сохранившуюся в БД информацию о уже выбранной стране. Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну давайте порассуждаем...

$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'] будет содержать value выбранного option-a *(я предполагаю, что где-то вы его корректно сохранили... потому что если нет - то это вообще задача с неизвестным числом неизвестных)*.

Давайте вычислим в вашем str_replace первые аргументы (предположим, я выбрал Украину):

**'>'.$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY']** превратится в **>1**
**'selected>'.$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY']** превратится в **selected>1**

Значит, вы берете вот такую строку (я укоротил до двух опшенов, чтобы проще было)

`<select size="1" name="country"><option value="0">Не скажу</option><option value="1">Украина</option></select>`, ищете в ней фрагмент **>1** и меняете его на **selected>1**.

А теперь сами скажите, что пошло не так? :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я просто совсем новичек. Нашел ошибку: >1 сменил на value= $_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'] а selected>1 на selected value="'.$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'] и заработало. Вот так:
str_replace('value="'.$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'].'"','selected value="'.$_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'].'"','<option value="0">Не скажу</option><option value="1">Украина</option>').'</select>

Comment: Ну вот, прекрасно :)

мысль работает - это главное. Опыт придет.